# Why bivariate_normal returns NaNs even if covariance is semi-positive definite?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

I have the following normal distributed points:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from matplotlib import mlab

mean_test = np.array([0,0])
cov_test = array([[ 0.6744121 , -0.16938146],
                  [-0.16938146,  0.21243464]])
```

The covariance matrix is definite semi-positive so it can be used as a covariance

```
# Semi-positive definite if all eigenvalues are 0 or 
# if there exists a Cholesky decomposition 
print np.linalg.eigvals(cov_test)
print np.linalg.cholesky(cov_test)
```

[ 0.72985988  0.15698686]

[[ 0.82122597  0.        ]
 [-0.20625439  0.41218172]]

If I generate some points I get:

```
 data_test = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_test, cov_test, 1000)
 plt.scatter(data_test[:,0],data_test[:,1])
```

[image: data]

**Question**:

Why does `bivariate_normal` method fail (return NaNs) when I try to plot the covariance contour?

```
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 
                      cov_test[0,0], cov_test[1,1],
                      0, 0, cov_test[0,1])
print Z
plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
```

Output:

```
 [[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 ..., 
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]]

 ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagonals of the covariance matrix are the variances, but the arguments `sigmax` and `sigmay` of `mlab.bivariate_normal` are the *square roots* of the variances.  Change this:

```
Z = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 
                      cov_test[0,0], cov_test[1,1],
                      0, 0, cov_test[0,1])
```

to this:

```
Z = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 
                      np.sqrt(cov_test[0,0]), np.sqrt(cov_test[1,1]),
                      0, 0, cov_test[0,1])
```