# contour throws an error trying to plot multivariate gaussian

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis

I have programmed a little script that simulates the EM-Algorithm and visualizes its iteration steps. However after the 5th iteration, it halts when trying to plot the updated estimated bivariate gaussian distributions.

I suspect that there's something fishy with my covariance matrices, but i'm not really sure. If i comment the contour plot, the script runs fine and works like it is supposed to (but of course it would be nice to follow the evolution of the estimated distributions). Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal


def expectationMaximization():
    # define multivariate gaussian distributions and generate observations
    u1 = [-1.5, -1.5]
    cov1 = [[0.2, 0.4],
            [0, 0.1]]

    u2 = [1, 1]
    cov2 = [[0.3, 0.4],
            [0, 0.3]]

    samples = 1000

    x1, y1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(u1, cov1, samples // 2).T
    x2, y2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(u2, cov2, samples // 2).T

    x = np.concatenate([x1, x2])
    y = np.concatenate([y1, y2])
    points = np.concatenate([np.column_stack((x1, y1)),
                             np.column_stack((x2, y2))])

    # initialization of classifier models
    uk1 = np.array([-1.5, 1])
    covk1 = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])

    uk2 = np.array([1.5, -1])
    covk2 = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])

    w = np.array([1., 1.])
    gamma = np.zeros((2, samples))

    # sim loop
    for idx in range(9):
        ##########################################################
        # expectation #
        ##########################################################
        # update gamma
        gamma[0] = (w[0] * sp.multivariate_normal.pdf(points, uk1, covk1) /
                    (w[0] * sp.multivariate_normal.pdf(points, uk1, covk1) +
                     w[1] * sp.multivariate_normal.pdf(points, uk2, covk2)))
        gamma[1] = (w[1] * sp.multivariate_normal.pdf(points, uk2, covk2) /
                    (w[0] * sp.multivariate_normal.pdf(points, uk1, covk1) +
                     w[1] * sp.multivariate_normal.pdf(points, uk2, covk2)))

        ##########################################################
        # plot #
        ##########################################################
        plt.subplot(3, 3, idx + 1)
        plt.title('Iteration {}'.format(idx + 1))
        axes = plt.gca()
        axes.set_xlim([-3, 3])
        axes.set_ylim([-3, 3])

        # setup grid for bivariate gaussian plot (only needed once)
        if idx < 1:
            xmin, xmax = axes.get_xlim()
            ymin, ymax = axes.get_ylim()
            delta = 0.1
            xticks = np.arange(xmin, xmax, delta)
            yticks = np.arange(ymin, ymax, delta)
            xmesh, ymesh = np.meshgrid(xticks, yticks)

        # update mesh values
        z1 = bivariate_normal(xmesh, ymesh, covk1[0, 0], covk1[1, 1],
                              uk1[0], uk1[1], covk1[0, 1])
        z2 = bivariate_normal(xmesh, ymesh, covk2[0, 0], covk2[1, 1],
                              uk2[0], uk2[1], covk2[0, 1])
        z = (z1 - z2) * 10

        # plot pdf map and sample points
        plt.contour(xmesh, ymesh, z)
        plt.scatter(x, y, c=(gamma[0] - gamma[1]) * 10)
        plt.grid(True)

        ##########################################################
        # maximization #
        ##########################################################
        # update means
        uk1[0] = sum(gamma[0] * x) / sum(gamma[0])
        uk1[1] = sum(gamma[0] * y) / sum(gamma[0])

        uk2[0] = sum(gamma[1] * x) / sum(gamma[1])
        uk2[1] = sum(gamma[1] * y) / sum(gamma[1])

        # update covariance matrices
        # calc all distances
        dist1 = points - uk1[None, :]
        dist2 = points - uk2[None, :]

        # calc all outer products
        matrixSchaar1 = np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij', dist1, dist1)
        matrixSchaar2 = np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij', dist2, dist2)

        # calculate sum product of matrices and gammas
        covk1 = ((matrixSchaar1 * gamma[0][:, None, None]).sum(axis=0) /
                 sum(gamma[0]))
        covk2 = ((matrixSchaar2 * gamma[1][:, None, None]).sum(axis=0) /
                 sum(gamma[1]))

        # update w
        w[0] = sum(gamma[0]) / len(gamma[0])
        w[1] = sum(gamma[1]) / len(gamma[1])


def main():
    expectationMaximization()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Traceback:

```
    /usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py:1926: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  denom = 2*np.pi*sigmax*sigmay*np.sqrt(1-rho**2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bsp4.py", line 120, in <module>
    main()
  File "bsp4.py", line 115, in main
    expectationMaximization()
  File "bsp4.py", line 76, in expectationMaximization
    plt.contour(xmesh, ymesh, z)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2766, in contour
    ret = ax.contour(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1815, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5644, in contour
    return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1424, in __init__
    ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 864, in __init__
    self._process_levels()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1202, in _process_levels
    self.vmin = np.amin(self.levels)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2359, in amin
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 29, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to feel like a dupe.

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645510/why-bivariate-normal-returns-nans-even-if-covariance-is-semi-positive-definite).

In short, `bivariate_normal()` wants standard deviation values, not variances.

After correcting my mistake, everything works as intended.

Comment: Glad you found the problem! Feel free to accept your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Started as a comment, but became too long...

You are right to suspect your covariant matrices. Your `bivariate_normal` distributions, `z1` and `z2`, consistently become `nan` arrays after the 5th or 6th iteration. However, I don't think that necessarily means your code is flawed, it could just be an inconvenient numerical issue (I know nothing about the theory here).

At any rate, you can keep your contours up to the `i`th iteration before breakdown by setting the levels for your contour plot

```
levels = np.linspace(z.min(), z.max(), 20)
plt.contour(xmesh, ymesh, z, levels=levels)
```

since from what I can tell the `ValueError` comes about from the contours not being able to set its minimum value.

Comment: That's certainly better than nothing, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You put me on the right track! Found the solution in another answer on SO.